# TortoiseSvn - the filename or extension is too long

Tags: tortoisesvn

I ran into an issue with TortoiseSVN failing on an Update, due to `The filename or extension is too long`.

Reading the manual on long paths (http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#long-paths), it says that:

```
Why does this problem not affect TortoiseSVN? Because TortoiseSVN always provides absolute paths to the Subversion APIs.
```

However, this problem is happening with TortoiseSVN.  Searching on Google resulted in some posts saying that it should work, and some that it shouldn't.  I find it a big limitation to have to restrict paths to being under 255 characters in total.

Any idea if this issue can actually be circumvented?

Answer (score 1):

As the docs already state: there's no problem with paths longer than 148/255 chars in TortoiseSVN.

However: NTFS (and most other file systems) have a limitation that can you simply can not get around. That limitation is that filenames (including the file extension) must not exceed 255 chars (the full path can be longer). Also, each sub-path must not exceed 248 chars.

So for example:

```
c:\verylong....foldername\anotherverylong...foldername\longfilename.txt
```

1. verylong....foldername : maximal 248 chars long
2. anotherverylong...foldername : maximal 248 chars long
3. longfilename.txt : maximal 255 chars long

If your files are within that limit, then there's something else wrong.
(if you're storing the files on a disk formatted with FAT32, you'll have more restrictions on the path part lengths).

Comment: I know this is old, but this happened again recently. The issue is because the entire path is longer than 255.  Although the docs state that it has no problem with paths longer than 255 characters, it seems to have!   The full path is: `C:\Work\Work\Clients\Current\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\www\deploy\Content\scripts\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stream\test\integration\test-delayed-stream-auto-pause.js` which works out at 268 characters